# What is it meant by “preparing solutions on a blister”?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, solutions

I was recently looking into an aspirin hydrolysis preparation lab and noticed the following:
[image]

(This preparation was taken from http://www.kii3.ntf.uni-lj.si/analchemvoc2/file.php/1/HTML/SPEKTRA/kinetics2.htm)

What is it meant by *blisters*, and by extension, the droplets? Does this simply indicate a ratio of added solutions? For example, to prepare 9mL of 12.5 mg/L concentrated salicylic acid solution, I would add 1mL of solution A, to 1mL of solution B, to 7mL of distilled water? Does this sound right?

Comment: Apparently it refers to a "blister" or pocket tray, with small indentations corresponding to the grid in the image, used for microanalysis.

Comment: Dr Pippik is right. Something like chemistry on a chip. The archetype of this was searching for a good solvent on a tray, for whose that know it.